# Get notified with sound whenever the table row get inserted in table of html

Tags: javascript, html, audio, tr

I want to get sound notification whenever the row gets inserted in table. This row is fetched from database. When it gets printed on HTML page at client side sound notification should be generated. Please help to solve this issue.Thankyou!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your html inside body tag anywhere. src attribute can be changed.

```
<audio id="play" src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav"></audio>
```

and in javascript write this code where your row adding function is placed.

```
document.getElementById("play").play();
```